# Embedded coding for TI CC2652RB. How to receive a string of characters from uart and save them in sd card?

Tags: embedded

I am using a TI launchpad CC2652RB. I have to receive data from another microcontroller and store the incoming data into an SD card. I am able to receive data successfully but unable to write complete data into the file. Only the last set of received bytes get written to the file i.e. every time the new string received overwrites the previously written string into the file.I am attaching my code for reference. I think the problem is in usage of file pointer or buffer length.\

```
void *alarmThread(void *arg0)
{
 mqd_t *mqdes = arg0;
 int msg;
 UInt32 sleepTickCount;
 sleepTickCount = 100000 / Clock_tickPeriod;
 SDFatFS_Handle sdfatfsHandle;
 FILE *src;
 SDFatFS_init();
 add_device(fatfsPrefix, _MSA, ffcio_open, ffcio_close, ffcio_read, 
 ffcio_write, ffcio_lseek, ffcio_unlink, ffcio_rename);
 clock_settime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
 sdfatfsHandle = SDFatFS_open(CONFIG_SDFatFS_0, DRIVE_NUM);
 while (mq_receive(*mqdes, (char *)&msg, sizeof(msg), NULL) != -1)
 {
    src = fopen(inputfile, "w+");
    fseek(src,0,SEEK_END);
    //fwrite(&input, 1, 1, src);
    fwrite(textarray, 1, strlen(textarray), src);
    fwrite(buf, 1, strlen(buf), src);
    fflush(stdin);
    fclose(src);
    GPIO_write(CONFIG_GPIO_LED_0, CONFIG_GPIO_LED_ON);
    Task_sleep(sleepTickCount);
 }

 SDFatFS_close(sdfatfsHandle);

 return(0);
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is.  It seems contradictory that you can "view the data" but not "access the buffer".  Show your code.

Comment: And split your problem into subproblems. The obvious candidates being reading from UART and writing to SD card.

Comment: Yes please check i have corrected the question.

Comment: Check the open mode of your file. `w+` opens for writing and reading, but you want appending, don't you?

Comment: yes how can i do that please tell?